# How can I change default position of label with value in input range?

Tags: jquery, css

On my website I'm using the jQuery plugin [jRange](http://nitinhayaran.github.io/jRange/demo/) for styling range input. This plugin works very good, but I need that default label with value move and center. You solved it anyone? I do not want to interfere to the js code because I do not understand it too much.

Live example is on this [link](http://apartmany.jinda.cz/vysledkyhledani.html), after expand right sidebar.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked with jRange but you can attach a function to the onstatechange events and calculate the left padding and apply it to the label. You can use the width option to know its size and derive the label's X-position from there.

This way you do not have to change the jRange code, you just create an event on your own code.

I created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/imelgrat/km1dtpy9/3/) to show you how you can capture the onstatechange() event. It just shows the current value on a separate field.

This is the part where all the action happens. You can modify the code to alter the label's left margin, so that it's always centered on the value

```
onstatechange: function(value)
{
   $('#testvalue').val(value);
}
```